# How to display chinese characters in my rcp application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm trying to internationalize my RCP app using the RCP i18n mechanism but i'm facing a problem :

When I translate the String "Hello" in Arabic, I get "\u0645\u0631\u062D\u0628\u0627". I put this UTF-8 string in my `.properties` file and everything goes well.

But when I translate the String "Hello" in Chinese, I get "\u4F60\u597D" and when I put this UTF-8 string in my `.properties` file my RCP app do not render the string in chinese but using the annoying traditionals squares...

What am i doing wrong ?

PS : I precise that my i18n class is coded using the **Modern Eclipse Message** class style.

Comment: Generally speaking, [proerties files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) are encoded in ISO 8859-1 with Java-style UTF-16 escape sequences. Java strings are UTF-16. I don't see where UTF-8 comes into it. Ensure the font your SWT control is using is capable of supporting the Chinese graphemes either directly or via platform-level font substitution.

Comment: Did you tried to configure your workspace do UTF-8? Doing so will recompile your classes to UTF-8

Comment: @McDowell How can i do that ?

Comment: @LuizE. I already did that and it does not work...

Comment: @mmoulis - by using a charmap-style application to inspect the fonts for the appropriate grapheme/code point and by reading the documentation/sources for the SWT implementation on your operating system.

Comment: @McDowell Thanks a lot, i will try that in a few. I keep you in touch!